# Some basic thinking regarding flow of code. To create or not to create new variables

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner c# programmer and I'm curious which of the variants from bellow it's better from the point of view of the compiler and so on.

Variant 1

```
string file = "20071201.22002300.wmv"; //name of the file is YYYYMMDD.HHMMHHMM.wmv
string[] tmp= file.Split('.');
DateTime startDate= new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(0, 4)),
                                 Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(4, 2)), 
                                 Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(6, 2)), 
                                 Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(0, 2)), 
                                 Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(2, 2)), 0);

DateTime endDate =new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(0, 4)), 
                               Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(4, 2)), 
                               Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(6, 2)), 
                               Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(4, 2)),
                               Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(6, 2)), 0);
```

Variant 2

```
string file = "20071201.22002300.wmv"; //name of the file is YYYYMMDD.HHMMHHMM.wmv
string[] tmp= file.Split('.');
int year = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(0, 4));
int month= Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(4, 2));
int day = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(6, 2));
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(0, 2));
int minute = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(2, 2));
int endHour= Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(4, 2));
int endMinute = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1].Substring(6, 2));
DateTime startDate= new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
DateTime startDate= new DateTime(year, month, day, endHour, endMinute, 0);
```

Generally i prefer to work as in first variant because i'm not working as a programmer so i don't work together with other programmers, I'm just creating tools to help in my job , and also i consider that the first variant it's easier for the compiler.

Please correct if i'm wrong and thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the filename be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: What's wrong with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)?  And apologies, there is no such thing as a "best" way, this is very non constructive.  If you can reformat your question in a more constructive manner (indicating what your issue is, what you are trying to achieve, etc), flag it and we'll take a look at it again (or the community will vote to open it).

Comment: Thank you all for answering i was interested from the performance point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the second because it is obvious what it is doing.

Also, you are not calling  `Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(0, 4))` etc. multiple times which you are doing in the first example.

**Update**

Even better, use something like this:

```
string file = "20071201.22002300.wmv";
string[] tmp = file.Split('.');

var baseDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tmp[0], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var startTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp[1].Substring(0, 4), "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp[1].Substring(4, 4), "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var startDate = baseDate + startTime;
var endDate = baseDate + endTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the second variant better because people tend to forget things. If I look at a peace of code a few months later I have to understand it again.

If something is visually simpler to understand it is always the better choice IMHO.

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand." - Martin Fowler in "Refactoring"

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will output exactly the same thing for each version.
FWIW, I would suggest debugging would be easier for you using the second method, as each temporary variable has a name, which helps keep it syntactically valid in your head.

Comment: I don't think it will output the same thing, `Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0].Substring(0, 4)` is being called multiple times in the first example but only once in the second.

Comment: @Joey: It would have to be a stunningly poor compiler to not realise there were sereral identical expressions and not use one result for them all :|

Comment: I've checked the IL, in the first example it calls System.String.Substring and System.Convert.ToInt32 more times than in the second example.

Comment: @Joey: Wow - good call. Very surprised about that. There are no writes to that array between the reads!

Comment: I guess it can't be sure no other thread has written to the array or that `Substring` and `ToInt32` will return the same thing each time they are evaluated.

Comment: @Joey: did you check both debug and release with optimizations?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second version for two reasons:

1. It is obvious what happens in it, in my opinion this is invaluable if you have to start working on the code again after not using it for a while.
2. In the second version, all the variables can be inspected in the debugger, this might not be super important in this example, but in other cases this could be valueable.

Comment: Unless you will throw away the code after writing a single-use utility, you are always working with another programmer: Yourself, the next time you have to change the code. Good point about being able to inspect the intermediates when debugging (or logging...), as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be clean & clear. There is no difference for compiller, and from performace point of view the overhead is vrey little, or may not be at all. So the second variant is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elegant solution

```
        string dateString = "20071201.22002300.wmv";
        string sStartDate = dateString.Remove(dateString.Length - 5, 4);
        string sEndDate = dateString.Remove(dateString.IndexOf('.')+1, 4);
        string format = "yyyyMMdd.HHmm";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        dateString = dateString.replace(".wmv", String.Empty);
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.ParseExact(sStartDate, format, provider);
        DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(sEndDate, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use both methods depending on the circumstances.

The 1st method I use if the variable is only going to be used once. The 2nd I use if I am going to use the variable multiple times.

This probably doesnt affect performance much but I feel its pointless to declare a variable then only use it once then disregard it, but also it is pointless to do the same conversion / cast on a value multiple times when it can be done once and stored in a variable.

In the 1st example I would say it could be made more readable by just commenting what the code actually does.